# How to use ActivityResultContract in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019, androidx

I am trying to make use of ActivityResultContract of AndroidX in Xamarin but cannot find any relevant documents or information to it. I have implemented the ActivityResultLauncher-ActivityResultContract in native android, created an .aar with API based on them and trying to build a DLL. But can't do the same in Xamarin. For eg. the ActivityResultContract in Xamarin Android is a non-grneric type as opposed to native. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Based on my search, i onlu could find the document for the navite android. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/result/contract/package-summary

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT The link you shared was useful for the native android code, but doesn't help for Xamarin. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to get a few of them working. e.g. StartActivtyForResult

declare a member
ActivityResultLauncher arlStartForResult;
Then in OnCreate()

```
arlStartForResult = RegisterForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), this);
```

Immediately the "this" will a red squiggly, so let VS add the IActivityResultCallback to your class and generate the empty

```
public void OnActivityResult(Object p0)
{

}
```

This is where it gets messy because you have to cast the Java.Lang.Object.

The following is an example of a Google Sign In.

```
public void OnActivityResult(Object p0)
        {
            // Introduced AndroidX.AppCompat 1.2.0.7 and AndroidX.Fragment 1.3.0.1 
            ActivityResult result;

            if (p0 is ActivityResult)
            {
                result = p0 as ActivityResult;

                if (result.ResultCode == (int)Android.App.Result.Ok)
                {
                    Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task = GoogleSignIn.GetSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.Data);
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.Result as GoogleSignInAccount;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(account.Email))
                        FirebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.IdToken);
                    else
                        UpdateUI(null);
                }
            }
        }
```

I've not had success with getting Permissions e.g.

```
arlRequestPermission = RegisterForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), this);
```

I guess this needs more work with the bindings. I suppose for now it would be better to go back to the previous nugets for both Activity and Fragment.

Comment: This makes use of the predefined `StartActivityForResult` in the `ActivityResultContracts`. In my .aar I have API which makes use of `ActivityResultLayncher<T>` and `ActivityResultContract<Input, OutPut>`. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Have you reported it on https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues

Comment: Yes, I have raised when you suggested to and they are yet to reply.

Comment: @user2153142 Are you then just calling `arlStartForResult.Launch(yourintent)` to start the process?