# How to pass request code in ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, androidx

I am updating some Xamarin.Android code to use the newer AndroidX APIs. The old way to launch an activity in my project was like this:

```
var intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(SomeActivity));
intent.PutExtra("someVariableA", a);
intent.PutExtra("someVariableB", b);
StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

The new way is with `ActivityResultLauncher` object:

```
activityResultLauncher.Launch(intent);
```

But how do I pass the request code? (second parameter in `StartActivityForResult`)

Comment: Purpose of `requestCode` was to differentiate results in `onActivityResult`, with `ActivityResultLauncher` API it becomes an internal detail and you no longer have to handle it - when result comes it gets passed down to `ActivityResultCallback` you defined when registering your `activityResultLauncher`.

Comment: For details of this problem, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66541013/how-to-use-activityresultcontract-in-xamarin-android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you do not need onActivityResult(). That way was old.You now have launchers for specific purposes.Create a function like this:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> imageActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            uri -> 
               //do something with uri
            });
```

And you want to launch this, just write:

```
imageActivityResultLauncher.launch("image/*");
```

For more details refer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654043/12555686